# Socket io complaining about CORS

Tags: java, websocket, socket.io, cors, netty

I started from the netty socketio demo.
The demo works locally.
But if I run it on a server, it does not work anymore (even though the client and server are on the same machine).

Chrome, FF and IE are complaining about

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://myserver:9092/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1401964309289-2&sid=1OyDavRDf4WErI-VAAAI.
>   This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or
>   enabling CORS.

I tried to set the origin in the configuration

`config.setOrigin("*:*")`

But no success..

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.
Netty socketio is supposed to support CORS since version 1.6.6/1.7

Anybody had a similar issue ? I can't find a working solution on the forum..

Thanks a lot.
Romain

**EDIT**

I can actually access my websocket with pure javascript, targetting ws://....

So the issue seems to be with socket.io, because socketio requires to use http://...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late anwser. But socket.io is a fake implementation of websocket.
this is the reason why it does not behave as websockets.